# how to "reset" a combobox using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, reset

i have a select dropdown on a webpage:

```
<select class="designs" id="color" name="Color">
 <option value="">Select Color . . .</option>
 <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
 <option value="White">White</option>
 <option value="Light">Light</option>
</select>
```

and i am trying to find the right jquery code to select the first entry on that combobox (the one with option value ="" and the text of "Select Color . . ."  (this is the setting that is on the page during original load before the user makes any changes)

I am doing this off of a button click link that says "Reset".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. And because the value of the element you want to preselect is empty you pass an empty string:

```
$('#color').val('');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#color option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");

$('#color')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .empty() function to clear the option of the combo box.

```
 $('#color').empty();
```

Comment: This is removing the select tag, rather than selecting the first option.